# Should gaining 200+ reputation, on one site (askubuntu) give me +100 associated site reputation bonus, on the same site.

Tags: support, bug

Today I passed 200 reputation on this site, only to then in quick succession, without doing anything, pass 300. I looked at my reputation log and it looks like I gained 100 for "passing 200 on an associated site", I knew that his happens, but not that I'd gain 100 reputation on the same site I gained the 200 on. Should this have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be feedback.

Your reputation on AskUbuntu was 198.

You received an Up vote on a question taking your reputation to 208.

This gave you an extra 100 points all your other sites.

In the process this took your reputation on Stack Overflow above 200 which gave you an association bonus on Ask Ubuntu.

I have no idea if this is supposed to be the intended behaviour however.

Comment: I've only just realized I never accepted this ages ago... sorry.