# 100+ reputation when hitting 200

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just passed 200 reputation on AskUbuntu, and then I received another 100 reputation for `Association Bonus`.

The 100+ bonus because I reached 200 on AskUbuntu didn't push me past 200 on any other Stack Exchange sites, so what are these 100 points from?

When I looked for another answer I saw [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6495/should-gaining-200-reputation-on-one-site-askubuntu-give-me-100-associated) but I didn't have any other sites with 100 rep before I reached 200, and thus AskUbuntu is the only Stack Exchange site which I have over 200 reputation on.

Comment: It's correct - you receive AssocBonus on **all** sites, including the one you earned it on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reputation is a rough measurement of your *experience* using the system. So once you gain 200 points on **any** site, you will be given a 100-point *head start* on **all sites** in the network (past, present, and future) to reflect that experience.

The "association bonus" is simply a way to say that you already have experience elsewhere, so you shouldn't have to start from scratch on every other site you join.

Comment: Ok. AskUbuntu is the only site I have over 200 rep on, and I did get a assoc bonus on AskUbuntu?

Comment: @DaboRoss That is by design... for consistency. Once you earn the association bonus, you get +100 on *all* sites.

Comment: Suppose I already have 200+ rep in one account and have received +100 in all accounts and if my another account reaches 200, will I again get +100 rep in all accounts?

Comment: @Apurva You only get the +100 association bonus on each site once. Think of it this way: When you have sufficient experience anywhere on the network (200 rep), all of your accounts will *start* with 100 rep instead of 1... retroactively.